# Split a 2d array into four equal parts

Tags: arrays, matrix, 2d, divide

I'm pretty new to programming in general. I have a 2d array that I have to split into 4 equal parts. The size of the array is a number that is the power of 2.

The tricky part is, that I have to check if the char values in the divided array the same, If not, then divide it again until every char is the same, or only one is left. For easy testing I just filled up the matrix with 'a' characters.

Thanks for the help, feel free to ask anything or for more specifications.

This is what I have so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      int meret = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
       if (Math.Log(meret,2)%1 !=0)
       {
             Console.WriteLine("Error");
       }
       else
       {
             char[,] matrix = new char[meret, meret];
             for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
             {

                  for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                  {
                        matrix[i, j] = 'a';
                   }
              }               
       }
            
}
```

I don't really know how to continue from here

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: It is c#, sorry I forgot to add that